# How can I combine 2 django query into one with object limit

Tags: python, django

I have multiple type of obj_type in database

What i am currently doing is

```
a =  Search_model.objects.filter(obj_type="mall", city=city)[:2]

b = Search_model.objects.filter(obj_type="store", city=city)[:2]
```

and then combine a and b so it gives me:-

```
[{"name":"a","obj_type":"mall"}, {"name":"b","obj_type":"mall"}{"name":"c","obj_type":"store"}, {"name":"d","obj_type":"store"}]
```

what i want is something like this

```
    if not search_in == None:
        search_in_queries = [q for q in re.split(",", search_in) if q]

        for query in search_in_queries:
            search_in_dict.append(('obj_type__contains', query))

        search_in_query = [Q(x) for x in search_in_dict]
    else:
        search_in_query = None
```

## such that value of search_in is "mall,store"

```
a =  Search_model.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, search_in_query), city=city)[:4]
```

but it gives me all mall type obj

```
[{"name":"a","obj_type":"mall"}, {"name":"b","obj_type":"mall"}{"name":"c","obj_type":"mall"}, {"name":"d","obj_type":"mall"}]
```

so my query is how can i achieve the above result in one query

Comment: Do you have any unique constraint based data? I mean any grouped data? you might use `annotate` group them and fetch two first records.

Comment: can you give any example syntax

Comment: I guess this needs plain SQL and would be hard to do with DJango ORM. Which sql backend are you using?

Comment: right now i am using sqlite3 but will be using postgres in production

Comment: I have added an answer which might give you an understanding of lazy evaluation of django querysets

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried searching with a list user `__in`. So construct a list of the things you want to filter.

```
Search_model.objects.filter(obj_type__in=["mall", "store"], city=city)
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in

Comment: Please read the question correctly. top 2 records of both `mall` and `store`

Comment: ordered by what?

Comment: yes @NagarajTantri you are correct i just want to combine 2 database calls into one to achieve the above result

Answer (score 0):

If it's Postgres, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` along with raw sql:

```
Search_model.objects.raw("SELECT id, obj_type from (
        SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY obj_type) AS rn 
        FROM search_model t
    ) WHERE rn < 3 and obj_type in ('mall', 'store')"
);
```

Would not prefer this way, as last I checked sqlite3 has no `ROW_NUMBER`.

For SqlLite3 you can fire:

```
SELECT id, obj_type
FROM search_model t1 
WHERE id in ( 
   select id from search_model t2 
   where t2.obj_type = t1.obj_type 
   order by t2.obj_type desc limit 2
) 
ORDER BY id, obj_type DESC;
```

With Django ORM, we might [look into](https://mattrobenolt.com/the-django-orm-and-subqueries/), Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and generally passed around without actually hitting the database:

```
from django.db.models import Q

mall_items = Search_model.objects.filter(obj_type="mall", city=city).values_list("id", flat=True)[:2]
store_items = Search_model.objects.filter(obj_type="store", city=city).values_list("id", flat=True)[:2]

print Search_model.objects.filter(Q(id__in=mall_items)|Q(id__in=store_items))
```